# Get information from the browser's network console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom-events

I want to access my browser's network console output via JavaScript or maybe another language.

*Here is a screenshot of the Firefox network console on YouTube:*

[image: Firefox Network console on YouTube]

I just want to retrieve every URL my browser GETs, and do it in JavaScript, if possible (I insert my scripts in the page using the Firefox Scratchpad).

### Edit: A bit more information about my project

I want to download a collection of "text to speech" samples generated by a website. But I don't want to use their API, because I know exactly how much samples I need (the number is above 300, so I don't want to do it manually).

Comment: i think you need to write your own firefox addon for this.

Comment: Doesn't it exist already? An addon to access the console output? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a normal JS script inside your browser won't give you access to this Firefox Panel, due to security reasons. But an alternative (For Google Chrome) is to type `chrome://net-internals/#events` in the Chrome address bar. This will open the Network Monitor. There you can type Ctrl+Shift+J or Cmd+Option+J (On Mac OS) and gain access to all HTTP events with JavaScript directly in the console.