# Get resource headers from javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am trying to get information on resources requested from a page from javascript.  I have looked at window.performance.getEntriesByType, and this gets me useful timing information, however I'm also trying to get information such as any cookies being set by a resource etc.

Essentially, the information held in the 'network' tab of chrome/firebug etc.  I appreciate it is probably different between browsers, but a starting point is all I need!

Comment: Have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747928/get-information-from-the-browsers-network-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers for every request the browser makes are not exposed to JavaScript, as far as I know.

The only thing you can do is get repsonse headers for AJAX requests. See: [jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)

Comment: That is what I feared! May have to do something server side to get that info. Thanks.